# Using a AngularJS Factory in a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, factory

OK so Im trying to create a Factory that will make a call to my REST api to retrieve data. All was fine until I updated to Angular 1.6 which forced me to use Promises and so I decided to try factories out:

```
var registerApplication = angular.module('applications', ['ajoslin.promise-tracker']);

registerApplication.factory('HTTPFactory', ['$http', function dataService($http) {

    var applications = {};

        applications = function getApplications() { $http ({
                'url': '/adminapi/getApplications',
                'method': 'GET',
                'cache' : true
            }).then(function(response){
               // return response.data;
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            });
        }
    return applications;
}]);

registerApplication.controller("ApplicationController", ['HTTPFactory',     function ($scope, HTTPFactory) {

    $scope.applications = {};
    getApplications();

    // when landing on the page, get all applications and show them
    function getApplications() {
        HTTPFactory.getApplications().then(function(response){
            $scope.applications = response;
        });
    }
}]);
```

However I'm getting this error:
    angular.js:10859Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating     'HTTPFactory.getApplications')

I've tried several ways and all seem to give me an error of some form, what am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Factory` is not properly injected.

```
registerApplication.controller("ApplicationController", ['HTTPFactory', function ($scope, HTTPFactory) {
```

should be

```
registerApplication.controller("ApplicationController", ['$scope', 'HTTPFactory', function ($scope, HTTPFactory) {
```

Furthermore, the following piece of code needs to be fixed.

```
applications = function getApplications() {
    // Logic
}
```

Should be replaced with by fixing the closure problem and also removing `.then()` from the logic of the factory.

```
applications.getApplications = function() {
    return $http({
        'url': '/adminapi/getApplications',
        'method': 'GET',
        'cache': true
    });
}
```

Comment: Fixed that problem but now I get Error: HTTPFactory.getApplications is not a function. (In 'HTTPFactory.getApplications()', 'HTTPFactory.getApplications' is undefined)
which was a error I was previously having prior to making some changes.

Comment: @RudolphRedNose please review.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Now to figure out why my UI didn't update... One step closer though. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote and select the answer if you may pls.

Comment: HTTPFactory.getApplications().then(function(response){
            $scope.applications = response;
        });

Please log the console and check if you are getting the correct response.

Answer (score 1):

first change the factory like this

```
registerApplication.factory('HTTPFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var applications = {
          getApplications : getApplications
    };

        function getApplications() { 
            return $http ({
                'url': '/adminapi/getApplications',
                'method': 'GET',
                'cache' : true
            })
        }
    return applications;
}])
```

you don't have to write the promise inside factory just return the http req to controller and catch the promise in there.

In the controller add string scope to array

`registerApplication.controller("ApplicationController", ['$scope','HTTPFactory',     function ($scope, HTTPFactory) {`

```
registerApplication.controller("ApplicationController", ['$scope','HTTPFactory',     function ($scope, HTTPFactory) {

    $scope.applications = {};
    getApplications();

    // when landing on the page, get all applications and show them
    function getApplications() {
        HTTPFactory.getApplications().then(function(response){
            $scope.applications = response;
        });
    }
}])
```